# Brian Goetz: SafePoint example - is it really thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

In Java Concurrency in Practice by Brian Goetz there is the following example (listing 4.11 shortened).

```
public class SafePoint {
    private int x, y;
    public SafePoint(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public synchronized int[] get() {
        return new int[] { x, y };
    }

    public synchronized void set(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Is it really thread-safe? `x` and `y` are neither `volatile` nor `final`, and they are set without locking on `this` which means another thread invoking `get()` may see stale values (zeros). Do I miss something here?

Comment: If x and y were final the setter makes no sense.

Comment: "they are set without locking on `this`": The setter is synchronized, so the set _is_ locking on `this`.

Comment: Extending Seelenvirtuose's comment: a `synchronized` method is always synchronized on `this`. If you use `synchronized` to synchronize statements/blocks, you have to specify the synchronization-object explicitly.

Comment: The question you are asking has a name.  Google for "Safe Publication"  or  "Safe Initialization" in Java if you want to learn all the gory details.

Comment: @jameslarge have you read the title? I'm reading a book on these topics and it's an example from it. As I see, the issue here is that `x` and `y` are set in constructor without synchronization on `this` which means another thread reading them further is not guaranteed to read values which were passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The method is thread-save as indicated by `synchronized`. As for your attributes `x` and `y` in your example those are only written in the constructor. Therefore you do not need to make them `synchronized`. If you implement some kind of setters for `x` and/or `y` you need to make those setters `synchronized` and the attributes [`volatile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html).

Comment: Sorry, there is a setter which I missed. Edited.

Comment: @AlexeyBerezkin As explained in the answer: if you have a setter, you need to make the attributes `volatile` to avoid reading stale values.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose But setting values in the constructor is not synchronized.

Comment: If the contructor ist called with 'new SavePoint' the call will return, when the constructor has finished. So you do not have to make it `sychronized', because no one can chance the values before that.

Answer (score 1):

> @jameslarge have you read the title?...

OK, I looked up "safe publication" in the index of the book that you are reading, and here's what it said in section 3.5.3:

> A properly constructed object can be safely published by; initializing an object reference from a `static` initializer, storing a reference to it into a `volatile` field or an `AtomicReference`, storing a reference to it into a `final` field of a properly constructed object, or storing a reference to it into a field that is properly guarded by a lock.

So, the answer depends on how the `SafePoint` class is used.

If thread A constructs a `SafePoint(5, 15)` instance and then stores it in a non-`final`, non-`volatile`, non-`static` field, and then thread B calls `safePoint.get()`; the value returned to thread B could be `[0, 0]`, or it could be `[5, 0]`, or `[0, 15]`, or `[5, 15]`.

If the `safePoint` field is `final` or `volatile`, or if it is a `static` field that was set by a static initializer, then the value returned to thread B will always be `[5, 15]`.

---

This example prints `result = [5, 15]` in *my* environment, but if my reading of Mr. Goetz book is correct, then the JLS *allows* it to return any of the other three possibilities.

```
public class SafePointDemo {
SafePoint safePoint;

void threadAwork() {
    safePoint = new SafePoint(5, 15);
    sleep(15000);
}

void threadBwork() {
    sleep(10000);
    int[] result = safePoint.get();
    System.out.println("result = [" + result[0] + ", " + result[1] + "]");
}

private void sleep(long n) {
    try {
    Thread.sleep(n);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    //do nothing
    }
}

class SafePoint {
    private int x, y;
    public SafePoint(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    }

    public synchronized int[] get() {
    return new int[] { x, y };
    }

    public synchronized void set(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SafePointDemo safePointDemo = new SafePointDemo();
    Thread threadA = new Thread(() -> safePointDemo.threadAwork());
    Thread threadB = new Thread(() -> safePointDemo.threadBwork());
    threadA.start();
    threadB.start();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the integers are not final, by only giving them values in the constructor you are effectively making them final since the pointer to the object is not available to the caller until the integers have been set.

The synchonization of the get method only guarantees that only one thread is able to execute the get method at a time, any other threads will be suspended until the first is finished.

Comment: Sorry, there is a setter which I missed. Edited.